# This question had 10 tags (5 tags duplicated) in Review

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, review

Bug report - whilst reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181101/need-help-redirecting-urls-with-parameters-in-apache), it showed 10 tags.

Sadly I can't provide any more insight into this. It "just happened" when reviewing normally.

I've retagged it now with simply: [mod-rewrite](/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite)

I can't rollback (no rollback link on the revision history) - not sure if it's a privs problem, or what.

One thing I can say is that I opened the actual question in another tab when I saw it... it only had 5 tags. The 10 tags only showed on the Review page.

[image: a]

Comment: It just repeated the tags for some reason.

Comment: You should probably change your question title and question to indicate that. Your current title is misleading.

Comment: If you roll back your edit does it still occur? *Do you have privilages to roll back, maybe a mod could try in order to reproduce the problem.**

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty weird one.

Digging in, there's no history entry with multiple tags; inserting a task doesn't modify it's tags (I recreated this task locally to double check that); the same code used to render tags in the review queue is used on the question page, so they *shouldn't* have differed; it wasn't an audit task (so no data faking could have gone sideways).

Uhm.  Cosmic rays maybe?

Comment: Haha, accepted just for the Cosmic rays ;)